# Button 'over' state on Dreamwever navbar button when returning to page with browser back button

Tags: dreamweaver, navbar

Here is my problem - I have button menu inserted with Dremweaver Navigation Bar. It swaps couple of images in the button link depending on mouse over/press. Buttons seem to work correctly when I use menu bar the first time. Although when I go to certain page from menu link and return back using back button in browser, the last pressed button retains it's press/mouse-over state. When I press refresh button, the problem dissapears. Can anyone know remedy for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What quite likely is happening is that the browser isn't reloading the page when you hit the back button, but rather un-freezing the state of the page when you left it. Personally, I'd not worry about it, but you could add an unload event handler that sets the state back to the state you want it in. I've never used the built in nav bar, or at least it's been so long that I've forgotten that I eve had, so not sure how you'd accomplish this. The code that I've looked at in the past isn't anywhere near what might be called "standard" JavaScript practice, but I'd bet the code is 8-10 years old.

Beyond that you'll have to link to your page (or a jsfiddle of it) so that someone can see all of the code in question to be able to recommend a solution.